# JNI IMU code not compiling "base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘JNIEnv’"

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface, native

I'm working on a native module to allow use of the RPI sense hat in java and my native will not compile:
At the moment I'm just trying to return the data as strings, if you have a simpler way please show me.
Here is the source file (SenseHat.cpp):

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "SenseHat.h"
#include "RTIMULib.h"


RTIMU *imu;
RTPressure *pressure;
RTHumidity *humidity;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_SenseHat_init(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj) {

    RTIMUSettings *settings = new RTIMUSettings("RTIMULib");

    imu = RTIMU::createIMU(settings);
    pressure = RTPressure::createPressure(settings);
    humidity = RTHumidity::createHumidity(settings);

    if ((imu == NULL) || (imu->IMUType() == RTIMU_TYPE_NULL)) {
        printf("No IMU found\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //  This is an opportunity to manually override any settings before the call IMUInit

    //  set up IMU

    imu->IMUInit();

    //  this is a convenient place to change fusion parameters

    imu->setSlerpPower(0.02);
    imu->setGyroEnable(true);
    imu->setAccelEnable(true);
    imu->setCompassEnable(true);

    //  set up pressure sensor

    if (pressure != NULL)
        pressure->pressureInit();

    //  set up humidity sensor

    if (humidity != NULL)
        humidity->humidityInit();

}

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_SenseHat_getTemperature(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj) {
   RTIMU_DATA imuData = imu->getIMUData();
   if (humidity != NULL)
      humidity->humidityRead(imuData);
   return ((*env)->NewStringUTF(env,imuData.temperature));
}

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_SenseHat_getHumidity(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj) {
   RTIMU_DATA imuData = imu->getIMUData();
   if (humidity != NULL)
      humidity->humidityRead(imuData);
   return ((*env)->NewStringUTF(env,imuData.humidity));

}

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_SenseHat_getOrientation(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj) {
   RTIMU_DATA imuData = imu->getIMUData();
   return ((*env)->NewStringUTF(env,imuData.fusionPose));
}
```

The full errors is:

```
SenseHat.cpp: In function ‘_jstring* Java_SenseHat_getTemperature(JNIEnv*, jobject)’:
SenseHat.cpp:53:18: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘JNIEnv’
    return ((*env)->NewStringUTF(env,imuData.temperature));
                  ^
SenseHat.cpp: In function ‘_jstring* Java_SenseHat_getHumidity(JNIEnv*, jobject)’:
SenseHat.cpp:60:18: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘JNIEnv’
    return ((*env)->NewStringUTF(env,imuData.humidity));
                  ^
SenseHat.cpp: In function ‘_jstring* Java_SenseHat_getOrientation(JNIEnv*, jobject)’:
SenseHat.cpp:66:18: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘JNIEnv’
    return ((*env)->NewStringUTF(env,imuData.fusionPose));
```

^

Compile code:

```
gcc -I /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/include/ -I /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/include/linux/ -shared -o libSenseHat.so SenseHat.cpp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JNIEnv` is declared a bit different for C and C++, see `jni.h` for details. In few words in C we use

```
(*env)->NewStringUTF(env,imuData.temperature);
```

In C++ it should be

```
env->NewStringUTF(imuData.temperature);
```

As you see C++ version doesn't need `env` dereference and passing it as first parameter to JNI functions.